# htaccess to escape percent (%) from URL

Tags: .htaccess, kohana-3

Having percent sign inside URL, returns bad request (error 400) to the browser. I have a filename that have percent (`%`) sign, resides at server.

Original File name:

```
204153_20090605_Aluminiumacetotartraat_DCB_oordruppels_1,2%.pdf
```

URL in browser after clicking on download link:

```
http://www.example.com/204153_20090605_Aluminiumacetotartraat_DCB_oordruppels_1%2C2%25.pdf
```

This returns 400 error with "bad request". I am using Kohana 3.

Existing `.htaccess` file contents are as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

<Files .*>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny From All
</Files>

RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

Comment: I would rather try to modify the file name and remove that `%` and `,`

Answer (score 0):

Try the [B flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags) to ensure the `%25`, unescaped to `%` by mod_rewrite, is re-escaped back to `%25` when inserted back into the target path.

```
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PTB]
```

Comment: You forgot the comma in `[PT,B]`.

Comment: Thanks @Gumbo Error disappeared, But it returned 500 error as it could not resolve %25 to %. In access log I got---127.0.0.1 - - [22/Oct/2010:18:29:42 +0530] "GET /204153_20090605_Aluminiumacetotartraat_DCB_oordruppels_1,2%25.pdf HTTP/1.1" 500 22514 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.11) Gecko/20101012 Firefox/3.6.11"