# 301 redirect with "%" in string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Someone linked to my site from nice place but the moron type the wrong URL, he did %20 at the end of it (probably his site did that). So I want to redirect http://example.com/%20 to http://example.com, because http://example.com/%20 is of course going to http://example.com/404 cuz that one is not valid URL.

I tried this:

```
rewriterule ^%20(.*)$ http://example.com$1 [r=301,nc]
```

But it just doesn't work. Looks like the `%` character has to be somehow escaped or something. So i tried also

```
rewriterule ^\%20(.*)$ http://example.com$1 [r=301,nc]
```

to give the `%` its original meaning by escaping it but it doesn't seem to be working either. Also read [htaccess to escape percent (%) from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996726/htaccess-to-escape-percent-from-url) but the solution presented there doens't seem to be working either. Anyone has idea how to do this? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match `%20` in `RewriteRule` using `\x20`:

```
RewriteRule ^\x20(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```