# URL rewriting for university bingo website

Tags: php, .htaccess

This is my .htaccess file's code:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^alluniversitiesview/([^\.]*)\.html$    alluniversitiesview.php?search=$1    [NC,L]    # Handle product
RewriteRule    ^search/([^\.]*)\.html$    index.php?search=$1    [NC,L]    # Handle product
ErrorDocument 404 /search/404.html
ErrorDocument 401 /search/401.html
ErrorDocument 500 /search/500.html
ErrorDocument 403 /search/403.html
ErrorDocument 400 /search/400.html
```

My requirement: 
If you go [to](http://universitybingo.com/search/HARVARD+UNI5V!.ER&#37SITY375E.html)

```
http://universitybingo.com/search/HARVARD+UNIV.html
http://universitybingo.com/search/HARVARD+UNI5V!.ER&#37SITY375E.html
```

Working fine.

But when url contains (%) it does not work like above

EXAMPLE from [universitybingo.com](http://universitybingo.com)

But not working
    http://universitybingo.com/search/HARVARD+UN%IV.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%` is the escape char for URLs.

But as per other answers like [htaccess to escape percent (%) from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996726/htaccess-to-escape-percent-from-url) or https://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/4220265.htm 
you can try with the [B flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags) of the `mod_rewrite` like:

```
RewriteRule    ^alluniversitiesview/([^\.]*)\.html$    alluniversitiesview.php?search=$1    [NC,L,B]    # Handle product
RewriteRule    ^search/([^\.]*)\.html$    index.php?search=$1    [NC,L,B]    # Handle product
```

Answer (score 1):

first of check mod rewrite engine is on or not ?

after you can using below html code:

```
RewriteRule ^alluniversitiesview/([^\.]*)\.html$ alluniversitiesview.php?search=$1    [NC,L,B]    # Handle product
RewriteRule ^search/([^\.]*)\.html$ index.php?search=$1    [NC,L,B]    # Handle product
```